# How to parse this JSON Array in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want the name, email and image for each TAG.I have to show in List element.

```
{
   "response":[
      {
         "name":"Brajendra Mishra",
         "email":"test1@seologistics.com",
         "address":"Information Service\r\nParliament of Canada\r\nOttawa, Ontario K1A 0A9",
         "aboutus":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. ",
         "image":"http:\/\/74.52.209.213\/lab\/event\/img\/attachments\/photos\/small\/4f2a5a71-acc0-4319-b1ca-14774a34d1d5.jpg"
      },
      {
         "name":"Toney Grey",
         "email":"test2@seologistics.com",
         "address":"Information Service\r\nParliament of Canada\r\nOttawa, Ontario K1A 0A9",
         "aboutus":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. ",
         "image":"http:\/\/74.52.209.213\/lab\/event\/img\/attachments\/photos\/small\/4f1d4283-5204-4f16-90d6-69924a34d1d5.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "count":2
}
```

I tried a lot but not able to do.

Just let me know the Loops, how to reach the values for each name, email, image etc, how to hold.

Comment: I am sorry man, we need more info. What is the first piece of JSON, what is the second one? Also, are you not using the JSONObject? Are you using ArrayLists?

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response. Give me some time, m giving u  more info.

Answer (score 9):

I generate a solution for ur ussue.

```
JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(jsoninputstring);
        for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++,start++) {
             JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

             String name= menuObject.getString("name");
             String email= menuObject.getString("email");
             String image= menuObject.getString("image");
        }
```

Comment: What's the "start++" jazz?

Answer (score 5):

try like this

where `jObj` is response which you get from server.

```
try { 
        JSONObject get_string = new JSONObject(jObj.toString()); 

        jsonProduct_jsonarray = new JSONArray();

        jsonProduct_jsonarray = get_string .getJSONArray("response");

        // Receive the JSON object from server
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonProduct_jsonarray.length(); i++) {

            System.out.println("GOT JSON VALUE ");
            JSONObject c = jsonProduct_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name= c.getString("name");
            String  email= c.getString("email");
            String  address= c.getString("address");
            String  aboutus= c.getString("aboutus");
            String   image= c.getString("image"); 
        }
```

goto this [working example, this might help you out](http://imagelistviewdynamic.blogspot.in/)