# Parse json objects and arrays android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have this JSON that I want to get in to my android app

```
{

    "json":{


        "albums":[{"id":"1","name":"Best Sumer colections","singer":"Dj Tiresto","genre":"Trance","mix":"yes","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                                            [
                                             {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                                             {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                                                                                                                                 ]
                  },
                  {"id":"2","name":"Best Sumer colections","singer":"Dj Tiresto","genre":"Trance","mix":"yes","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"3","name":"O viatza","singer":"Maria Bieshu","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"4","name":"De petrecere","singer":"Gerghe tzopa","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"5","name":"De petrecere","singer":"Gerghe tzopa","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  },
                  {"id":"6","name":"De petrecere 2013","singer":"Gerghe tzopa","genre":"Trance","mix":"no","thumb":"alb1.png","songs":
                  [
                   {"song":"Nothins else1","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else2","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else3","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else4","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else5","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},
                   {"song":"Nothins else6","artist":"ionsuruceanu","mp3":"mp3_URL","mp4":"mp4_URL","thumb":"alb1.png"},


                   ]
                  }

        ]


    }


}
```

But I'm only getting `Reading a NULL string not supported here.` from the logcat.
So here is my code that I use to parse the json:

```
// Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of albums

            albums = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ALBUMS);

            // looping through All albums
            for(int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String album_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String album_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String album_singer = c.getString(TAG_SINGER);
                String album_genre = c.getString(TAG_GENRE);
                String album_thumb = c.getString(TAG_THUMB);

                // songs are again JSON Object
                JSONObject songs = c.getJSONObject(TAG_SONGS);
                String artist = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_ARTIST);
                String mp3 = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_MP3);
                String mp4 = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_MP4);
                String song_thumb = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_THUMB);
                String song_title = songs.getString(TAG_SONG_TITLE);
                Log.v("--", "Albums \n"+" "+album_id+" "+album_name+" "+ album_genre+" "+album_singer+" "+album_thumb);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So can anyone help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`JSONArray songs = c.getJSONArray(TAG_SONGS);`**

**`songs`** is an Array of JSONObjects and you should be handling it the same way are you are parsing **`albums`**.

Comment: can you give me the solution in more details.. thanks for the answer

Comment: `songs` is an array of JSON objects, where each of those objects have the tags mp3, mp4, artist, thumb, etc.

Comment: You are doing it pretty much correct except for the songs part. So, for that, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529558/how-to-parse-this-json-array-in-android.

Comment: Now I get 03-30 16:46:10.662: W/System.err(21641): org.json.JSONException: No value for albums
Can you help me now?

Comment: Sure! Could you please post your updated code in your question ?